# Change the URL of posts by category

Tags: posts, permalinks

I have bunch of posts and I would like to organize their link by the categories with a smart way.
Right now I have the links of the posts with the following schema:
http://localhost:81/wordpress/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

I know that this schema can be changed at: Settings -> Permalinks, but this is not exactly what I would like...

What I want is to put a logic behind it. Lets suppose that I have the following categories:

- easy lessons
- advanced lessons
- pro lessons

And lets suppose that we have the following posts by categories:

- EasyLessons: The ABC, Saying Hello
- AdvancedLessons: Simple present, Present Perfect
- ProLessons: Present perfect continuous, Black words

So as a result I would have the following links of the posts:

- localhost:81/easylessons/theabc
- localhost:81/easylessons/sayinghello
- localhost:81/advancedlessons/simplepresent
- localhost:81/advancedlessons/presentperfect
- localhost:81/advancedlessons/presentperfectcontinuous
- lo=alhost:81/advancedlessons/blackwords

What is your opinion, is it possible to solve this problem? If so, would you be so kind as to help me in this matter? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh it was quick! I figured it out, so simple. I only had to change the scheme to the following:
.../%category%/%postname%/

Great! Thanks anyway ;)